# Как расположить 2 баннера подряд

Tags: html

Как расположить 2 баннера подряд, а не в столбик? размер у обоих одинаков 468х60

Answer (score 3):

Таблицы для разметки давно уже отошли.

Почитайте [пример](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-razmestit-dva-sloya-po-gorizontali), поэкспериментируйте.

Знание css обязательно для любого вебмастера, хотя бы на начальном уровне,
особенно в грядущем HTML5

Comment: Целиком отошли?
Видел пару грамотных сайтов с таблицами, а ещё больше комбинирование таблиц и div'ов. Но при этом, конечно же, без CSS не обойтись!

Answer (score 0):

Заставить банера вести себя как строчныые элементы. Используйте CSS:

```
dispaly:inline-block
```

Comment: через css не умею может скажете как это будет через таблицы?

Comment: @Никола Кривошея: вы и вправду не знаете, как сделать таблицу из одного столбца и двух строк? А _какую_ таблицу вы умеете сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если уж вы хотите таблицами:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src=# width="468" height="60">
</td>
<td>
<img src=# width="468" height="60">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Чтобы впредь не оскорблять элементарными вопросами чувства местных кулхацкеров (они тут бывают нервные), почитайте самоучитель HTML [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml) или [здесь](http://www.postroika.ru/html/1step22.html). Написано очень доступно. Или [погуглите](https://www.google.ru/search?q=html+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) другой источник.

Answer (score 0):

[Кроссбраузерный](http://jsfiddle.net/C5pME/) ответ (: работает с ие 6 версии и дальше.
html -

```
<div class='holder'>
  <div class='banner red'></div>
  <div class='banner blue'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.holder{
    min-width: 940px;
  height: 60px;
}
.banner{
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
  width: 468px;
  height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```